# Can I pre-trained BERT model from scratch using tokenized input file and custom vocabulary file for Khmer language

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, bert-language-model

I would like to know if it's possible for me to use my own tokenized/segmented documents (with my own vocab file as well) as the input file to the `create_pretraining_data.py` script (git source: https://github.com/google-research/bert).

The main reason for this question is because the segmentation/tokenization for the Khmer language is different than that of English.

```
Original:
វា​មាន​មក​ជាមួយ​នូវ

Segmented/Tokenized:
វា មាន មក ជាមួយ នូវ
```

I tried something on my own and managed to get some results after running the `create_pretraining_data.py` and `run_pretraining.py` script.  However, I'm not sure if what I'm doing can be considered correct.

I also would like to know the method that I should use to verify my model.

Any help is highly appreciated!

### Script Modifications

The modifications that I did were:

1. Make input file in a list format

Instead of a normal plain text, my input file is from my custom Khmer tokenization output where I then make it into a list format, mimicking the output that I get when running the sample English text.

```
[[['ដំណាំ', 'សាវម៉ាវ', 'ជា', 'ប្រភេទ', 'ឈើ', 'ហូប', 'ផ្លែ'],  
['វា', 'ផ្តល់', 'ផប្រយោជន៍', 'យ៉ាង', 'ច្រើន', 'ដល់', 'សុខភាព']],  
[['cmt', '$', '270', 'នាំ', 'លាភ', 'នាំ', 'សំណាង', 'ហេង', 'ហេង']]]
```

** The outer bracket indicates a source file, the first nested bracket indicates a document and the second nested bracket indicates a sentence. Exactly the same structure as the variable `all_documents` inside the `create_training_instances()` function*

2. Vocab file from unique segmented words

This is the part that I'm really really having some serious doubt with. To create my vocab file, all I did was find the unique tokens from the whole documents. I then add the core token requirement `[CLS], [SEP], [UNK] and [MASK]`. I'm not sure if this the correct way to do it.

Feedback on this part is highly appreciated!

3. Skip tokenization step inside the create_training_instances() function

Since my input file already matches what the variable `all_documents` is, I skip line 183 to line 207. I replaced it with reading my input as-is:

```
  for input_file in input_files:
      with tf.gfile.GFile(input_file, "r") as reader:
          lines = reader.read()
      all_documents = ast.literal_eval(lines)
```

### Results/Output

The raw input file (before custom tokenization) is from random web-scraping.

Some information on the raw and vocab file:

```
Number of documents/articles: 5
Number of sentences: 78
Number of vocabs: 649 (including [CLS], [SEP] etc.)
```

Below is the output (tail end of it) after running the  `create_pretraining_data.py`

[image: create_pretraining_data_khmer_output]

And this is what I get after running the `run_pretraining.py`

[image: 20191119_sample_4]

As shown in the diagram above I'm getting a very low accuracy from this and hence my concern if I'm doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you seem to have very little training data (you mention a vocabulary size of 649). BERT is a huge model which needs a lot of training data. The english models published by google are trained on at least the whole wikipedia. Think about that!

BERT uses something called WordPiece which guarantees a fixed vocabulary size. Rare words are split up like that: `Jet makers feud over seat width with big orders at stake` translates to wordPiece as: `_J et _makers _fe ud _over _seat _width _with _big _orders _at _stake`.

`WordPieceTokenizer.tokenize(text)` takes a text pretokenized by whitespace, so you should change the BasicTokenizer, which is run before the WordPieceTokenizer by you specific tokenizer which should separate your tokens by whitespace.
To train your own WorPiece-Tookenizer, have a look at [sentenePiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece), which is in bpe mode essentially the same as WordPiece. 
You can then export a vocabulary list from your WordPiece model.

I did not pretrain a BERT model myself, so I cannot help you on where to change something in the code exactly.